# use computed variables in react-native animated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

How to use Animated To animate the size of a circle based on a view, animating the Width and Height, deriving the other values needed? (radius and centered left/top)
Animating WH, deriving the radius is WH/2, the centered Left and Top is Left - radius and Top - radius.  How do I compute these to use in Circle's style?  (I'm doing 3 interpolations which work but there should be a better more efficient way)

```
const CircAnim = (props) => {
  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current  // Initial value : 0
  fadeAnim.setValue(0);
  const wh = fadeAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [props.startSize, 0],
  })
  const radius = fadeAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [props.startSize/2, 0],
  })
  const centeredLeft = fadeAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [props.style.left - props.startSize/2, props.style.left],
  })
  const centeredTop = fadeAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [props.style.top - props.startSize/2, props.style.top],
  })
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 3000,
      }
    ).start();
  }, [props.restarting])
```

Answer (score 0):

And, here is my answer.  Very simple, just a matter of understanding the specs.
Of course, this is simple math, so the next question is, how to perform more complex math on these values.

```
  const radius       = Animated.divide(wh,2);
  const centeredLeft = Animated.subtract(props.style.left,radius);
  const centeredTop  = Animated.subtract(props.style.top,radius);
```